# Socket There is an error in XML document

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Недавно начал пользоваться Socket и столкнулся с проблемой переда данных, то есть если, я отправляю byte[] обьемом болиее 100 кб. он у меня выдает ошибку при дисериализации документа,

> Error = "There is an error in XML document (13, 2970)."
>   Message = "Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: _Message, MainData, DataMessages. Line 13, position 2970."

```
            ReceiveSocket = Listen.AcceptSocket();
            if (!Form1.ValueSendMessages.OffGetMessage)
            {
                Byte[] Receive = new Byte[256];
                using (MemoryStream _Message = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Int32 ReceivedBytes;
                    do
                    {
                        ReceivedBytes = ReceiveSocket.Receive(Receive, Receive.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                        _Message.Write(Receive, 0, ReceivedBytes);
                                                }
                    while (ReceiveSocket.Available > 0);
                    using (StringReader ReconvertString = new StringReader(Encoding.Default.GetString(_Message.ToArray())))
                    {
                        XmlSerializer XmlData = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataMessages));
                        DataMessages GetDataContract = (DataMessages)XmlData.Deserialize(ReconvertString);
```

> Здесь ошибка

```
DataMessages GetDataContract = (DataMessages)XmlData.Deserialize(ReconvertString);
```

А вот самое интересное, когда я провожу переходы в данном код через отладчик, проблема исчезает, ни разу не повторилась, такое ощущение что он не успевает передать сразу все данные по переменным.

**Если после ReceiveSocket = Listen.AcceptSocket(); установить Thread.Sleep(2000); то все работает, в чем может быть проблема**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что чтение из сокета не гарантирует доставку всего сообщения за раз. Если вы знаете длину посылаемого сообщения, читайте до тех пор, пока не получите все байты сообщения. Если не знаете, постройте протокол общения так, чтобы размер передавался вначале.

Цикл по `ReceiveSocket.Available` неверен: вы можете выбрать данные быстрее, чем они придут, и данные не появятся в сокете до тех пор, пока посылающая сторона не доотправит их (или промежуточный сервер не пропустит). К этому моменту вы уже выходите из цикла чтения.